# disable copy and paste in datagridview

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview, keyboard-shortcuts, keyevent

I am a beginner in .net. This could be a silly question. I want to disable <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> keyboard shortcuts.

Before asking here I tried these codes [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzbc92t.aspx) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11755747/1577396) (*not working*)

```
private void dgvMain_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        this.dgvMain.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText;
    }

    private void dgvMain_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        this.dgvMain.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.Disable;
    }
```

**and also**

```
this.dgvMain.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.Disable;
```

`dgvMain` is datagridview
I maybe missing something here.

EDIT:
    The properties for my datagridview which I have altered are:

```
AllowUserToResizeColumns      -- False
AllowUserToResizeRows         -- False
ClipboardCopyMode             -- disable
ColumnsHeadersHeightSizeMode  -- AutoSize
Dock                          -- Fill
ReadOnly                      -- True   
TabStop                       -- False
```

Please help

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619535/how-do-you-disable-a-datagridviews-keyboard-shorcuts) thread for how to handle the shortcuts. You can use it for Ctrl + C and Ctrl + V.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't spell out the not-working part, so I can only guess that you are referring to the TextBox part of the grid.

It should be enough to just have `ClipboardCopyMode = Disable` but if the TextBox of the cell is in edit mode, that property gets ignored.  You would have to disable the keys and the ContextMenu yourself:

Example:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  dgvMain.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.Disable;
  dgvMain.EditingControlShowing += dgvMain_EditingControlShowing;
}

void dgvMain_EditingControlShowing(object sender,
                                   DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
  TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
  if (tb != null) {
    tb.ContextMenuStrip = new ContextMenuStrip();
    tb.KeyDown -= TextBox_KeyDown;
    tb.KeyDown += TextBox_KeyDown;
  }
}

void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Control && (e.KeyCode == Keys.C | e.KeyCode == Keys.V)) {
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this.**

```
private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = e.Control as TextBox;
            tb.ShortcutsEnabled = false;
        }
```