# Prevent copying content from specific datagrid text column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I want to prevent users from copying content from a column in my WPF DataGrid, which I've defined as a DataGridTextColumn

Setting `ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}"` has not worked, which to me is the most obvious way to prevent any content from being copied.

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header=Field"
                        Binding="{Binding Name}"
                        ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

I expect the output to be string.empty (or not even be included in the ClipboardContents) since the ClipboardContentBinding is set to null. Instead, it's actually copying the Name.

Edit 01:
I tried: `ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Static Binding.DoNothing}"` but that didn't work. I get an exception:
`System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Data.BindingBase'.`

What *does* work, is setting a binding to a path that will fail. For example:

`ClipBoardContentBinding="{Binding InvalidPath}"` where `InvalidPath` does not exist on the object that's being bound... Is there a better way than relying on a magic-string path?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780961/disable-copy-and-paste-in-datagridview

Comment: @Sach, I'm not using Windows Forms, but WPF.

Comment: This is not the exact answer, it's a point in the right direction. Take a look at that accepted answer, suppressing keypresses might still work for you.

Comment: This will work but it prevents the column from being edited.  You can set the column's `IsReadOnly` to true.  If you need to be able to edit, then, I think, you will need to provide a `DataTemplate` using the column's `CellStyle` property.  And then use Sach's suggestion to disable some operations on the `TextBox`

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to disable copy by restricting copy command in `CommandManager.PreviewExecuted` event.

XAML

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header=Field" Binding="{Binding Name}" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <EventSetter Event="CommandManager.PreviewExecuted" Handler="textBox_PreviewExecuted"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Code Behind

```
private void textBox_PreviewExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Copy)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish what you want with the following.

Include namespace xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

Define an empty string resource:

```html
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <x:Static x:Key="stringEmpty" Member="sys:String.Empty" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Reference the resource as Source instead of as Path:

```html
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Key}" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=stringEmpty}}" />
```